# designing a electric heater with nichrome wire

Tags: voltage, power, current, heater

I have a 24 gauge nickel chromium wire
i have 12volts 400watts dc power supply
help me in finding temperature of wire if length is 0.3m
please help me in calculation with the above data

Comment: Temperature, even for regular wire, cannot be calculated in a simple equation because it involves geometry, gradients, and differential equations. Airflow too in your case which is even trickier. Easier to just test or have feedback and monitoring.

Comment: How much hot air do you need?  What temperature does it start at?

Answer (score 1):

You can't predict the wire temperature without knowing the rate of heat loss. Stable temperature is achieved when *electrical power in = heat lost to environment*.

[image]

*Figure 1. A hot-air soldering workstation. Image source: [RS](https://ie.rs-online.com/web/p/soldering-stations/1244133).*

Where controlled air temperature is required, such as in the device shown in Figure 1, a temperature sensor is installed *downstream* of the air heater. This feeds back to the controller and the controller adjusts the power level to get the desired temperature.

There are many calculators and tutorials online which may give you a rough guide to length and voltages required. Note that your specification is incomplete as you have not included the volume of air to be heated and the inlet air temperature.

Note also that if you switch to metric and Celcius this will be a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a complicated problem, but not an unsolvable one. Unless you have access to sophisticated thermal modeling (computational fluid dynamics, a very expensive piece of software) you will have to determine this by experiment.

Start with the characteristics of your blower and size a suitable heating element for that blower (your nichrome wire, wound on a mica support.) Equip your setup with a thermal probe and measure the temperature at the nozzle vs. input power.

You can adjust the wire length depending on how close you get to the target nozzle temp: more wire will lower it, less wire will raise it assuming a given voltage (W = E^2/R). While this seems like some work, it's a lot cheaper than spending your annual salary on Ansys.

This article could be helpful: https://www.stanmech.com/articles/sizing-your-heater-and-blower-the-relationship-between-air-flow-and-temperature

And here: https://www.stanmech.com/articles/the-basics-of-heat-calculations

---

Just for fun, let's do a back-of-the-envelope calculation for your heater. Let's say your blower is hair-dryer sized. Hair dryers are about 1500W, and are designed to have a nozzle temp of about 140F.

Assuming 240V line:

- Heater resistance for 1500W @240V: R = E^2/W = 38.4 ohms
- length of wire: R/(ohms/ft) = 38.4/6.5 = 5.9 ft.

From here: https://temcoindustrial.com/product-guides/wire-cable-and-accessories/resistance-and-non-resistance-wire/nichrome-wire

This would give you a starting point. Adjust accordingly.

Comment: Judging by the question I wouldn't mention the possibility of using 240 V in my answer!

Comment: There's a good chance OP is in India, or at the very least *not* in Japan, Taiwan or North America where 120V line is used.

Comment: I was thinking < 24 V would be safer.

Comment: To make enough wattage at 24V, the wire would need to be really, really short and the current really, really high. That's not really feasable with 30 ga nichrome wire. Really. ;-)

Comment: i have 12 v 400watts dc power supply.can you help me to achieve 212 Fahrenheit of air temperature with this.

Comment: It really depends on the airflow that you need. Without knowing that, it’s not possible to predict whether you will achive the target temperature. That said, the length of wire that will dissipate 400W can be estimated from the formula I gave. Resistance = 144/400 = .36 ohm, wire length will be .36/6.5 = .66 in. That’s not realistic. So, 10 wires in parallel will be .65 ohm per ft. Use 5-6 in x 10 wires in parallel and you will be close to the target.

Answer (score -3):

use the wire tio boil water use the steam in a raditaor to warm the air,

212F guaranteed.

Comment: it is of high cost for designing the boiler for this project and i need hot air as soon as within 2 minutes.so it is not possible